# convert Stream<List<String>> to List<String> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a `Stream<List<String>> to List<String>` in flutter
here is my code

```
Stream<List<String>> _currentEntries;

/// A stream of entries that should be displayed on the home screen.
Stream<List<String>> get categoryEntries => _currentEntries;
```

`_currentEntries` is getting populated with data from a database.
I want to convert `_currentEntries` into `List<String>`

I tried the following code but doesn't work:

```
List<List<String>> categoryList () async  {
  return await _currentEntries.toList();
}
```

I get the following error:

> A value of type `List<List<String>>` can't be returned from method `categoryList` because it has a return type of `List<List<String>>`

Can someone help how to solve this issues and convert a `Stream<List<String>` to `List<String>`?

Comment: Can you share the data returned from the database and how you want to format it?

Comment: @SanjaySharma The data type from the database is explained in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your return type for `categoryList`. You're returning as `List` of `List`s when the `Stream` only contains a single layer of `List`. The return type should be `Future<List<String>>`.

Use `.first`, `.last`, or `.single` in addition to `await` to get just a single element, and `toList()` should be removed.

```
Future<List<String>> categoryList () async  {
  return await _currentEntries.first;
}
```

*Also a quick tip: Dart automatically generates getters and setters for all fields so the getter method you show isn't necessary.*

Comment: hi Christopher, thank you for your answer.  i am facing a small problem is that i am calling the categoryList function and assign it to a List<String> such as   List<String> lit = bloc.categoryList();  this is producing an error:  a value of future<List<string>> cant be assigned to variable List<String>.  how can i solve this?

Comment: @yoohoo You have to `await` the `Future`. So do  `List<String> lit = await bloc.categoryList();`

Comment: textbook solution worked `List<int>? _audioStreamList =
        await _audioStreamCast?.first;`

Answer (score 7):

As title said, question is how to convert stream of some items to item. So what Christopher answered it is ok but only if you want to take the first value from the stream. As streams are asynchronous, they can provide you a value in any point of a time, you should handle all events from the stream (not only the first one).

Let's say you are watching on a stream from database. You will receive new values from database on each database data modification, and by that you can automatically update GUI according to newly received values. But not if you are taking just first value from stream, it will be updated only the first time.

You can take any value and handle it ("convert it") by using `listen()` method on a stream. Also you can check this nicely written [tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-stream-basics-for-beginners-eda23e44e32f) on Medium. Cheers!

```
 Stream<List<String>> _currentEntries = watchForSomeStream();

 _currentEntries.listen((listOfStrings) {
    // From this point you can use listOfStrings as List<String> object
    // and do all other business logic you want

    for (String myString in listOfStrings) {
      print(myString);
    }
 });
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly to converting.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea that Stream can **await** for the API call from the server, in my case  I'm using BLOC pattern and using `Future<List<String>> getCategoryList async () {...}` and to get the List I going to use like this:

```
Future<List<String>> getCategory() async {
    var result = await http.get();
    //Some format and casting code for the String type here
    return result;
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

For me I was working with List of maps and the maps has a model class Product

```
Stream<List<Product>> streamedProducts = yourStreamService();
    List<Product> prod = [];
    //listen to the stream and return the products
    await streamedProducts.listen((product) {
      for (Product element in product) {
        prod.add(element);
      }
      print(prod);
    });
```