# (Stream<List> doesn't support lists inside lists?) flutter firestore store list of objects

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

i have the following two classes in my flutter app. requisition class has a list of products i was able to save requisitions to firestorm with serialization without an issue. but when i retrieve data back it doesn't work i found that Stream<List> doesn't support lists inside lists. is they are any workaround for this issue i'm using provider package to manage state.

```
     class Requisition {
      String reqNo;
      String date;
      double totPrice;
      List<Product> products;
      // final double qty;
      String location;
    
      Requisition(
          {this.reqNo, this.date, this.products, this.totPrice, this.location});
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {
          'reqNo': reqNo,
          'date': date,
          'total': totPrice,
          'products': products.map((i) => i.toMap()).toList(),
          'location': location
        };
      }
    
      Requisition.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
          : reqNo = firestore['reqNo'],
            date = firestore['date'],
            // products = firestore['products'],
            location = firestore['location'],
            totPrice = firestore['total'];
    }

  

    class Product {
      final String desc;
      final double price;
      final double qty;
      // final String location;
    
      Product({this.qty, this.price, this.desc});
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {'desc': desc, 'qty': qty, 'price': price};
      }
    
      Product.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
          : desc = firestore['name'],
            price = firestore['price'],
            qty = firestore['qty'];
    }

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:construction_procurement_app/Models/Requistion.dart';

class FirestoreService {
  Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
 
  Future<void> saveRequsition(Requisition requisition) {
    return _db
        .collection('requisitions')
        .document(requisition.reqNo)
        .setData(requisition.toMap());
  }

  Stream<List<Requisition>> getRequsitions() {
    print('get reqs called');
    return _db.collection('requisitions').snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot
        .documents
        .map((document) => Requisition.fromFirestore(document.data))
        .toList());
  }

  

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054709/10285344

Comment: firestore returns data as  Stream<List> so i cant convert it to a normal list

Comment: To find an alternative, can you elaborate about Stream<List> doesn't support lists inside lists?