# How can I pass Stream to list flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm filtering a collection with this Stream, and I need to pass this to a List

I have Stream like this:

```
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    
        static Stream<List<CabModel>> cabsStream(String value) {
        return firebaseFirestore
            .collection('cabs')
            .where('space', isEqualTo: value)
            .orderBy('cab')
            .snapshots()
            .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
          List<CabModel> cabs = [];
          for (var cab in query.docs) {
            final cabModel = CabModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot: cab);
            cabs.add(cabModel);
          }
    
          return cabs;
        });
      }
```

My list:

```
    List<CabModel> cabsList = [];
```

Comment: [`Stream.toList`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/toList.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert Stream<List<String>> to List<String> in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054667/convert-streamliststring-to-liststring-in-flutter)

Comment: Doesn't work for me or I don't know how implement it :(

Answer (score -1):

You have to use SteamBuilder for live showing data.. and Future builder will not update data until app restart.

full details, go to this link.. https://youtu.be/ErP_xomHKTw
(video Duration =  10:23) you will see this part. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I used StreamBuilder y works great. But I'm trying to refactor my App using Getx.